# Help With Simple Sproutcore Task

Tags: iphone, ipad, html, scroll, sproutcore

I was wondering how difficult it would be to implement Sproutcore into my webpage for the simple task of being able to scroll DIV's on an iPhone or iPad with one finger instead of two.

Or is there an easier way?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pulling in SproutCore for just this purpose would be unwise, especially for a mobile app, as it would include far too much weight for very little added functionality for your app.

If you just want to have an iOS scroll view, there are other much lighter libraries for just this. A quick search (for "iOS html scroll view javascript") reveals:

http://code.google.com/mobile/articles/webapp_fixed_ui.html (how google does it)

Answer (score 1):

SproutCore is a complete web application framework; incorporating it into an existing design for the purpose of getting touch scrolling functionality is probably more tool than you need. I'd look at JS libraries which are just interaction libraries, not application frameworks.